# Why Google analytics request/ response is missing when using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, puppeteer

If google analytics code is added in a page, a gif request to https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect will be sent to record pageview.

I am not able to see any such requests with puppeteer. Below given is the code I used to print all response urls.

```
page.on('response', response => {

    console.log("URL: " + response.url());
    });
```

I am able to see all the calls in the network tab. But only a few are getting printed in the console. Am I missing something here?

My use case is to check if the analytics request is sent or not and to get its status.

Comment: Do you want to track requests or responses?

Comment: I just want to check if the response status is 200 or not.

Comment: I know that with the [`setRequestInterception`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) you can intercept this kind of requests regardless of who initiated. But  I don't know how to check for the response.